# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError after restore of local database from Heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app on Heroku (which is up to date and has run the latest migrations), when I download the database to my local postgresql database with this script:

```
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire --app myapp
echo "Captured database on heroku"
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp`
echo "Downloaded database"
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d cooking latest.dump
echo "Database restored"
```

And I start my local server I get an error like this:

ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.

I have tried deleting and resetting my old database with no change.

Comment: Have all your migrations run from your codebase locally? The error is reporting a pending migration. Does your `schema_migrations` table `version` column match the file name prefixes in your `db/migrate` directory?

Comment: Yes, I have run it locally, even tried a reset - but then I want to download the database as it is from Heroku and the error reappears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs when the version of the database (accessible via `ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version` in Rails or `select max(version) from schema_migrations` with SQL) is less than the highest migration version, as loaded from `db/migrate` and typically encoded in the filenames of the files in that directory.

It doesn't matter what you do to your database in terms of running migrations or resetting it as long as you are replacing it with the Heroku version afterwards. At that point, all that matters is how your database contents compare to the migrations in `db/migrate`.

Comment: I realize now I changed the number of a migration and thats why it failed, now it works.